# StartupNextInstance event no longer running in main thread after migrating .NET Framework app to .NET 7

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-7.0

I have several Windows Forms applications written in VB.NET and targeting the .NET Framework that I am migrating to .NET 7. They are single-instance applications and rely on the `MyApplication_StartupNextInstance` event to do various things including creating new forms.

When the application runs a second instance on .NET 7, I observe various problems that I traced back to the fact that this event handler is now running in a **worker thread** rather than the main thread. According to [Microsoft's documentation of the event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startupnextinstance?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), this event is supposed to run in the main thread.

As a minimal example, I created two Windows Forms VB.NET projects in Visual Studio 2022, one targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2 and another targeting .NET 7. Both projects have a single empty form "Form1.vb" and the project properties set to make this a single-instance application.

I then have the following code in ApplicationEvents.vb:

```
Private Sub MyApplication_StartupNextInstance(sender As Object, e As StartupNextInstanceEventArgs) Handles Me.StartupNextInstance
    Try
        Dim frm2 As Form1 = New Form1() 'Breakpoint here
        frm2.Show()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ERROR: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I ran the solution with the breakpoint set as specified above and show the Threads pane (Debug -> Windows -> Threads). Then I manually ran the .exe from Windows Explorer which raises the `StartupNextInstance` event and runs the above code.

The .NET Framework version of the code shows that the active thread is "Main Thread". The .NET 7 version of the code shows the active thread is ".NET ThreadPool Worker". When I proceed past the breakpoint, the .NET Framework version launches a second copy of the form and the .NET 7 version opens a broken form that won't respond to my input (it's more obvious if you add controls to the form).

If I add a WebBrowser control (which is a wrapper for the IE ActiveX control), the .NET Framework version of the code works as expected but the  .NET 7 version throws an exception "ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment", further demonstrating that the core of the issue is the difference in which thread the event runs under.

What is the correct way to interact with UI elements in the main thread from the `StartupNextInstance` event in .NET 7?

Comment: I just tested .NET 5, 6 and 7 projects and I'm seeing what you describe in 6 and 7 but, interestingly, .NET 5 worked the way you expect and the way you describe .NET Framework behaving. I'm wondering whether this change was by design and they simply haven't updated the documentation. Regardless, if you need to access existing forms on the UI thread then you need a solution to that issue. I have an idea but I'll need to test. I'll post an answer if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to ensure code is executed on the UI thread in a WinForms app is to test the `InvokeRequired` property of some control (forms are controls too) created on the UI thread and, if it's `True`, call the `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` method of the same control to marshal a method call to the UI thread. You might like to read about that in more depth [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?498387).

You can ignore the `InvokeRequired` property if you want, as `Invoke` will work even if it's called on the UI thread, although there will be unnecessary overhead. If you know for sure that the code will executed on a worker thread, the property check is less important too.

In this specific scenario, you can use this same technique. If your app has a startup form and that form will always be displayed for the life of the app, you can use it in the `StartupNextInstance` event handler to marshal a method call to the UI thread. Where you might have done this up to .NET 5:

```vb
Private Sub MyApplication_StartupNextInstance(sender As Object, e As StartupNextInstanceEventArgs) Handles Me.StartupNextInstance
    'Some code to execute on the UI thread here.
    MessageBox.Show("Hello from the UI thread")
End Sub
```

you could now do this for the same effect:

```vb
Private Sub MyApplication_StartupNextInstance(sender As Object, e As StartupNextInstanceEventArgs) Handles Me.StartupNextInstance
    MainForm.Invoke(Sub()
                        'Some code to execute on the UI thread here.
                        MessageBox.Show("Hello from the UI thread")
                    End Sub)
End Sub
```